# Does the [remote-login] wiki need an update?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just reviewed [this helpful edit suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/888227) and realised that Ubuntu 14.04 is the only currently supported Ubuntu the advice in the wiki is relevant to. What happened to `remote-login-service`, I wondered. I imagine systemd has eaten it.

Can anyone update [the remote-login wiki](https://askubuntu.com/tags/remote-login/info) to make it clearer what *remote-login* is and what's happened to it? Or is [remote-login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remote-login) a tag on its way to being of only historical interest? Or is this tag one we should just get rid of because it lacks specificity?

Comment: `remote-login-service` died because it was "buggy and unmaintained": https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/remote-login-service/+bug/1158373

Answer (score 3):

Alright, so, there are quite a few tags floating around for (roughly) the same thing:

- **[remote-login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remote-login)** - This tag, seeming to currently be for the `remote-login` service, but being used for anything remote.
- **[remote-access](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remote-access)** - The overarching tag for anything related to remoting in to any machine (SSH, VNC, and so on)
- **[remote-desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop)** - A subset of `remote-access`, seemingly meant for only graphical solutions.

Ideally, we'd get rid of as many of these tags as possible, which brings me to my proposal here:

1. Regarding [remote-login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remote-login), make it clear that it's meant for the legacy `remote-login` service. Users who want to ask questions about remote access to their machines should use [remote-access](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remote-access).
2. Regarding [remote-desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop), make it a synonym for [remote-access](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remote-access). Access is broader than desktop, and this prevents confusion with Microsoft's [Remote Desktop Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol).
3. Re-tag posts under [remote-login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remote-login) to [remote-access](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remote-access) as necessary. That is, where  questions are about general remote access to machines.

Of course, we also have the slew of specific tags, such as [ssh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ssh), [vnc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/vnc), [rdp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/rdp), and so on. These should be kept around, and should be used *in addition* to the [remote-access](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remote-access) tag.

There are rather few questions that I can see about *actual* `remote-login`, but it's still of historical note and is a valid tag in quite a few places, so I don't think it deserves burnination. However, as mentioned above, an update to the tag to show that it's unmaintained and is only to be used for the service would be a good idea.

Comment: The tag itself could be renamed to something like `legacy-remote-login`. Few bother to read tag excerpts.

Comment: Thanks a lot for shedding light on this. I'd assumed the [remote-desktop] tag was actually *supposed* to be for RDP. These tags seem a total mess. There's also a tag [remote] - seems to me [remote-access] could be a synonym of that if it's not actually about anything more specific. I agree with muru about renaming the tag in question to something less generic-sounding to prevent improper use.

Answer (score 2):

I should have researched more thoroughly before posting my question, but I hoped for some community insight on a topic I don't know about. Thanks for your help, Kaz Wolfe and muru.

This tag is being misused. Of the 48 questions that currently have it, I found only these that are actually about the buggy unmaintained and insecure `remote-login-service` the tag wiki refers to:

- [How to turn off Remote login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380032/how-to-turn-off-remote-login)
- [How can I enable remote login in 13.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372238/how-can-i-enable-remote-login-in-13-10)
- [How to Remove Guest Session and Remote Login from Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339579/how-to-remove-guest-session-and-remote-login-from-ubuntu-13-04)
- [Remote login on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455816/remote-login-on-ubuntu-14-04)

All of the others are about remote access in general.

I do not think a tag is justified for 4 questions and since the software is apparently obsolete, we cannot expect further questions about it (except possibly "what happened to `remote-login-service`?").

I will destroy the [remote-login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remote-login) tag unless there are strong objections, and re-tag the existing questions as appropriate.

I have asked [a follow-up question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18249/are-any-of-these-tags-remotely-useful) about what to do with the various `remote-` tags so I know *what* to best re-tag these questions with.