# Are any of these tags [remote]ly useful?

Tags: discussion, tags

A few days ago I asked [this question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18240/does-the-remote-login-wiki-need-an-update), and [this answer by Kaz Wolfe](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/18247/527764) pointed out that [remote-login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remote-login) is only one of several tags about remote stuff.

- [remote-desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop), 761 questions

  > Questions that refer to a software or an OS feature allowing applications, either command line programs or graphical applications, to be run remotely on a server, while being displayed locally.
- [remote](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remote), 446 questions

  > Anything involving something running on one computer and interacting with resources of another computer (e.g. display).
- [remote-access](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remote-access), 367 questions

  > the process of accessing a system remotely, over the network. eg via vnc or ssh.
- [remote-x-session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remote-x-session), 46 questions (no usage guidance)
- [remote-assistance](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remote-assistance), 5 questions (no usage guidance)

Should some of these tags be synonymised (or got rid of)? Kaz Wolfe suggested making [remote-desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop) a synonym of [remote-access](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remote-access). Is it useful, though, to distinguish [remote-desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop) from more general... remoteness?

It seems to me there's no use for the catch-all tag [remote](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remote), since [remote-access](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remote-access) seems general enough to do the same job. Am I wrong?

Comment: I would rather see those changed silently and not swarm the frontpage :P Is there someone with direct DB access?

Comment: @Rinzwind I don't swarm the front page when I destroy tags, and I fix everything I can about the posts when I edit them. Do you mean, there are a lot of posts? I agree that 400+ posts is a very long job. It would take many months to do properly. The [remote] tag could perhaps be synonymised to [remote-access] (or possibly vice-versa). In regards to your question, tags can be silently deleted on request, but that leaves no way to find and improve the untagged posts, unless they have no other tags and end up [untagged]

Comment: Add `x11-forwarding` to whatever `remote-xsession` might be about

Comment: The usage guidance should contain links to the (major) single-tool tags, e.g. “There‘s also an [tag:ssh], a [tag:vnc] and an [tag:rsync] tag, please add these tags as well if they fit.”

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_desktop_software) says the following:

> In computing, the term remote desktop refers to a software or operating system feature that allows a personal computer's desktop environment to be run remotely on one system, while being displayed on a separate client device... Taking over a desktop remotely is a form of [remote administration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_administration).

I think that Remote Administration covers [remote-desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop). [remote](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remote), [remote-access](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remote-access).

I don't like the current description of [remote-desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop) - I personally feel that it should refer to GUI access only, not command line programs.

My preference would be to create a new tag of [remote-administration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remote-administration) and make them all synonyms of it, but I can understand why this might not be the prefered solution - in which case I would agree with Kaz and make [remote-desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop) a synonym of [remote-access](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remote-access).

My pronouns are He / Him